# Why Pagination laravel ignores requests - skip, take

Tags: laravel, pagination, skip, take

I wanted to use `skip` and `take` but pagination does not work. Why does it not work?

Code:

```
    $posts = DB::table('posts')
        ->orderBy('id','desc')
        ->skip(9)
        ->take(3)
        ->paginate(3);



    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return ['posts' => view('blog.ajax.index')->with(compact('posts'))->render(),
            'next_page' => $posts->nextPageUrl()
        ];
    }
```

I definitely need to use pagination

Answer (score 2):

You can not use paginate and skip at the same time. so your alternate option would be something like this

```
$take = 100;
$skip = 9;
$currentPage = Request::get('page', 1);
$poster = DB::table('posts')        
    ->take(100)
    ->skip($skip + (($currentPage - 1) * $take))        
    ->orderBy('id','desc');
```

for pagination try

```
@if (Request::has('page') && Request::get('page') > 1)
<a href="{{ route('some.route', ['page' => Request::get('page') - 1]) }}">Previous page</a>
@endif

@if (Request::has('page'))
    <a href="{{ route('some.route', ['page' => Request::get('page') + 1]) }}">Next page</a>
@else
    <a href="{{ route('some.route', ['page' =>2]) }}">Next page</a>
@endif
```

Comment: I definitely need to use pagination

Comment: @ArmanTurebekov you can use pagination, also i mention pagination part in answer. and calculate the number of pages before you send the data to the view this is just example modify as per your requirement.

Comment: @ArmanTurebekov if you are satisfied with my answer please accept my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot about it

Comment: And we can implement all this in blade.php